# HighCharts - Inner line gradient for 3d effect

Tags: highcharts

I found a graph on the internet that I am trying to mimic.  The line has a linear gradient inside the line to make it appear cylindric.  Is there an option to add this in high charts?  I found I can apply a linear gradient with fixed xy coordinates but they are not relative to the line but the background of the graph it self.

[image: 3d line effect]

Comment: Hi @user1978109, Please check an example with multiple series: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/bre62ayu/ and with glows: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/hxdru163/ and let me know if any of these examples meet your requirements.

Comment: The glow appears to be on the outside while the 3d effect is done on the inside, its a light to dark gradient that is relative to the line inside.

Comment: user1978109 - but what about the example with multiple series: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/s6v9rnpu/

Comment: Its an interesting approach but the light source direction is not configurable like a gradient.  Also, performance would not be great with many series / points.

Comment: Hi @user1978109, Unfortunately, I see no other way. To increase performance, you can use [boost](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/advanced-chart-features/boost-module). You can also try a solution with duplicated path elements: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/at20yj4z/